# Regexp captured group backreference doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, backreference

I am experimenting with regex backreferences and I am stuck at some very simple case.

Regexp which does not match the whole input:
`([\D\s]+)(\d+)\1`

Input:
`Foo 12 bar`

Link: https://regex101.com/r/yfFLmc/1/

On the other hand, the same regex without backreference(but with repetition of first capturing group) matches the whole input correctly: `([\D\s]+)(\d+)([\D\s]+)`

Why the regex with backreference doesn't match the whole input?

Comment: Backreferences match the same text matched with the group pattern, not the same pattern. Backreferences are not subroutine calls. Just check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yfFLmc/2) with a subroutine call.

Comment: Ahaa, I see. Thank you very much! I indeed had wrong understanding - I actually need the subroutine call.